# Inverse of $x(x+2)$ given $x\ge -1$

Tags: inverse

Consider the function: $y=x(x+2)$ . Consider its domain to be $x \geq -1$ .

Graphically it makes sense that the inverse of this function is $-1 + \sqrt{x+1}$.

But how to compute it analytically? Thanks

Comment: Complete the square.

Answer (score 6):

Verbally, since the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x(x+2) = (x+1)^2-1$, we have that $f$

- adds one to its input,
- squares the result,
- and subtracts $1$.

An inverse function will do the opposite things in the opposite order:

- add $1$,
- take a positive or negative square root,
- subtract $1$.

Since we seek to invert a function whose domain includes arbitrarily large positive numbers, we reason that we will take the positive square root. So $$f^{-1}\left(y\right)=\sqrt{y+1}-1\text{.}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Multiply to get $y=x^2+2x$ and then use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$.